# How am I supposed to configure an Azure Hosted Agent VS2017 build for 9.1?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to deploy my Sitecore 9.1 solution to `Azure DevOps`. I'm using a Hosted VS2017 `Agent pool` to do that.

When it compiles my `*.sln` solution, an error shows up, explaining that WebApplication.targets is not found. How can I find this location on the Hosted Agent ?

> Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.

It seems that `MSBuild` tools are not installed on the distant machine.

This is a glance on my `azure devops` build task :

[image: Configuration of my Visual Studio build]

Comment: Take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12975170/772898

Comment: I've already looked at this post but it doesn't answer my problem because mine is located on Azure Hosted agent. I cannot install anything or modify its content. I need to reach the right URL for the project, which I don't know...

Comment: Take a look in that precise answer. It will enable you to use that in Azure DevOps just by copying BuildTargets into your solution

Comment: By copying BuildTargets into your solution may cause issues in a near future, I have being there a couple weeks ago. You have to install Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools on your agent using the following options Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools

Comment: Ok @ViniciusDeschamps but how can I install this Nuget Package ? Should I restore a nuget package with a specific task in my pipeline ? Or should I install it directly in my solution and reference it in each project ?

Comment: @ThomasGRIESMAR I am assuming you have a Azure DevOps agent somewhere, so you should install in the agent the Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools witht he options I am refering to. I think you should provide more details about your Azure DevOps environment: is it in cloud, on-prem or hybrid; do you have agents? where?. Also, I think this question does not belong in https://Sitecore.StackExchange.com, you should ask in https://StackExchange.com instead.